# How to create one query instead of two separated queries?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have two queries like this:

```
$stm = $db->prepare(" SELECT * from table1 where word = :word ");
$stm->bindValue(':word', $word, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stm->execute();

$iterator = 0;
while ($end = $stm->fetch()) {

    foreach ($db-query(" SELECT * from table2 where id = $end['id']") as $row) {
        echo $row['title'];
    }

    $iterator ++;
}
```

Now I want to know, is it possible to I write a sub-query instead of that separated query? In other word how can I write those two queries in one query?

Comment: Try like `SELECT * from table2 where id IN (SELECT id from table1 where word = :word)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is that you can do this in the database.  And you should.

A typical response is that you should learn `join`.  However, in this case, `in` or `exists` is more appropriate:

```
select t2.*
from table2 t2
where t2.id in (select id from table1 where word = :word);
```

I do find it surprising that the condition connecting the two tables is on a column called `id` in both tables.

Comment: Agreed ...! `IN` seems better. +1

Comment: You have implement your query using `IN`, But there is a [reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/subquery-optimization-with-exists.html)  which says for large dataset `EXISTS` definitely performs better having right indexes on the table. Well, still you believe `IN` is better in my case?

Comment: @Shafizadeh . . . MySQL has been improving the optimizations for `IN`.  Usually, I would use `EXISTS`, though.  I just thought `IN` would make it easier to follow the logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use join for this take a look at this query

```
    SELECT table1.id, table2.title
    FROM table1
    INNER JOIN table2
    ON table1.id=table2.id;
    WHERE word = :word
```

You can learn more about [joins from here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Is JOIN your solution?

```
SELECT main.*, joinedTable.* FROM T1 as main
LEFT JOIN T2 as joinedTable
ON main.id=joinedTable.id
WHERE main.word = :word
```

I Didn't try this out...

Answer (score 1):

Sure,  you can use `INNER JOIN`

```
$stm = $db->prepare(" SELECT t2.* from 
                       table1 t1  INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON (t2.id = t1.id) 
                       WHERE t1.word = :word "); 
$stm->bindValue(':word', $word, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stm->execute();

$iterator = 0;
while ($row = $stm->fetch()) {
   echo $row['title'];
   $iterator ++;
}
```